# select a class inside a section Tag

Tags: html, css

I have the following fiddle in which it works by hovering over a class,however I have not managed to make it work when surrounded by  tags. How can I make it work

Thanks in Advance

```
<section class="section1">
    <div class="ButtonChange">
        Hover Here
    </div>
</section>


<section class="section2">
    <div class="changecolor">
       Text Sample
    </div>
</section>



<div class="ButtonChange2">
    Hover Here 2
</div>


<div class="changecolor2">
    Text Sample 2
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Jhonc66/380k4m7g/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
.section1:hover ~ .section2 .changecolor {
    color:red;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for that, now how would I only select an specific class inside the section 1. Please see the following fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Jhonc66/380k4m7g/6/